# Java Enum not valid error

Tags: java

Why is this enum not valid ?

```
enum Type{

      MPEG-2=2,PASSED_PIDS_ID=3,DVB=4,ATSC=5,NA=6,UNDETERMINED=7

      }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a couple of syntax errors, one in the first identifier (the `-` is invalid in a variable name) and also in how you're setting your values.  You don't use `=` in an enum, but you can use a constructor instead.  Try this:

```
enum Type {

    MPEG2(2), PASSED_PIDS_ID(3), DVB(4), ATSC(5), NA(6), UNDETERMINED(7);

    private final int value;

    Type(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way to go. The ordinal() method on enums is meant to be used by Enum related Data Structures such as EnumSet etc.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `=<number>`, it is invalid. Also, the minus sign in the first type is not valid syntax.

The Enum has a method called `ordinal()` which returns the order of the Enum, but it is not recommended to rely on that, should you add any new Enum typed in the future, then the Enums after it in the list will all have an ordinal of one higher.

Should you wish to include some more data, then you can have a constructor, which you could use as example:

```
public enum Fruit {

    APPLE("Green"),
    BANANA("Yellow");

    private final String colourDescription;

    Fruit(String colourDescription) {
        this.colourDescription = colourDescription;
    }

    public String getColourDescription() {
        return colourDescription;
    }         
}
```

So for your example, it may be best to have no extra information, or create a constructor as above and pass a number in that way.

Comment: How  do i make it start from value 2 instead of 1??

Comment: @Codenotguru Not possible using `ordinal()` - will be better to use the constructor in that case.

Comment: private constructor? I thought Java enums all wanted to be default access? (ie, `Fruit(...){` rather than `private Fruit(...){`)

Comment: @Brian You never want to be able to call `new` on an enum

Comment: @Noel M default access on an enum constructor won't let you call new on it, ever.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a `-` in an identifier. Use `MPEG_2` instead. I also don't think the =[number] syntax is correct in Java.

Answer (score 1):

It's invalid because "-" is not valid character in an identifier. Using MPEG_2 instead of MPEG-2 will fix it.